# Is it possible to add dynamic library in static library under iphone application?

Tags: dynamic, static-libraries, xcode5.1

I am creating a static library that contains functionality I want to provide to some other applications. However, my static library requires libxml2.dylib and libsqlite3.0.dylib dynamic libraries. Now when I am compiling my static library, I got the error "libsqlite3.0.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library" and "libz.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library". 
Is there a way to add or link dynamic library to static library? Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "is a dynamic library, not added to the static library" warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572610/how-to-fix-is-a-dynamic-library-not-added-to-the-static-library-warning)

Comment: Short version: You can't.