# Convert .a to .dylib in Mac osx

Tags: macos, dynamic, shared-libraries, static-libraries, dylib

Is it possible to convert .a files to .dylib files in Mac osx?
I currently have libraryname.a and it can't seem to include it in my program as only .dylib libraries are included.

Is there also a command that shows static libraries used in a program via mac osx terminal?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible.  To convert `foo.a` into `libfoo.dylib`, try this command:

```
clang -fpic -shared -Wl,-all_load foo.a -o libfoo.dylib
```

On Linux, here's the equivalent command using `gcc`:

```
gcc -fpic -shared -Wl,-whole-archive foo.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive -o foo.so
```

Here's a complete example.

Let's start by creating (and testing) `libfoo.a`:

```sh
$ cat > foo.h
int foo();

$ cat > foo.c
int foo() {
  return 42;
}

$ cat > main.c
#include "foo.h"
int main() {
  return foo();
}

$ clang -c foo.c -o foo.o
$ ar -r libfoo.a foo.o
ar: creating archive libfoo.a

$ clang libfoo.a main.c -o main.out
$ ./main.out; echo $?
42
```

Now let's convert it into `libbar.dylib` and test again:

```sh
$ clang -fpic -shared -Wl,-all_load libfoo.a -o libbar.dylib
$ clang -L. -lbar main.c -o main.out
$ ./main.out; echo $?
42
```

Comment: is the reverse possbile? I mean can I have .a file for .dylib on macos?

Comment: I'm not sure, but some quick searching doesn't make me hopeful. If you try feeding `libfoo.dylib` into `ar`, it complains.  Also, `man ar | grep dynamic` returns nothing.  (Not a good sign.)  And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575470/162094) claims it's not possible.