# Build a c-shared dylib from golang for iOS (armv7/arm64)

Tags: ios, macos, archive, shared, dylib

Is there a way to build a dynamic library (dylib) from go code? I get it done for x86_64 and i386, but for arm64 and armv7(s) it says "buildmode=c-shared is not supported on darwin/arm". Why?
Or is there a way to convert a static a-library file into a dynamically linked Mach-O dylib?
I can merge the dylibs and a-files into one universal binary using lipo, but that still leaves them as static archives.

I'm sure there must be a command to convert a static archive into a dynamic Mach-O library. Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert .a to .dylib in Mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321911/convert-a-to-dylib-in-mac-osx)

Comment: Same concept applies to iOS, just use `xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch arm64 [rest of flags]`.

Comment: That is a good starting ooint, Thank you @Siguza - but I get error with missing Symbols like this:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_CFBundleCopyResourceURL", referenced from:
      _init_working_dir in storj_uplink.a(000021.o)
  "_CFBundleGetMainBundle", referenced from:
      _init_working_dir in storj_uplink.a(000021.o)

Comment: Ah, got it! Had to add -Framework CoreFoundation. Thank you @Siguza!

Comment: When I follow these instructions to compile the Storj uplink-c SDK, I got a runtime error:

libuplinkc.dylib`golang.org/x/sys/cpu.getisar0:
->  0x104d7b110 <+0>:  mrs    x0, ID_AA64ISAR0_EL1
    0x104d7b114 <+4>:  str    x0, [sp, #0x8]
    0x104d7b118 <+8>:  ret    
    0x104d7b11c <+12>: udf    #0x0

Did anyone encounter this? Described in more detail on 
https://github.com/storj-thirdparty/uplink-swift/issues/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Siguza gave me the correct hint. This is the final way to convert my static archive to a dynamic library for iOs - at least for arm64. I tried the same for armv7, but that lead to other issues and I decided to leave 32bit out here.

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7 -fpic -shared -Wl,-all_load libmystatic.a -framework Corefoundation -o libmydynamic.dylib
```